# Find an object in a generic list with Find method

Tags: asp.net, find, generics, predicate

```
class Cache
{
    int sizeOfCache;//no of RssFeedDocument 
    private List<RssFeedDocument> listOfRssFeedDocument = null;
}
```

i want to find a object in this generic list in class based upon `RssFeedDocument` 's property `FeedId`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using anonymous delegate:

```
Guid feedID = ...;
RssFeedDocument document = listOfRssFeedDocuments.Find(
    delegate(RssFeedDocument rfd)
    { return rfd.FeedId == feedID; });
```

The same, but with C# 3.0 lambdas:

```
Guid feedID = ...;
RssFeedDocument document = 
    listOfRssFeedDocuments.Find(rfd => rfd.FeedId == feedID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods, I think the easiest way is actually to use `Where`:

```
listOfRssFeedDocument.Where(doc => doc.FeedId == someId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<RssFeedDocument> filteredList = listOfRssFeedDocument.Find(delegate(RssFeedDocument d) { return d.FeedId = x; });
```

Reference: [List`<T>`.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't able to use LINQ you could use something along the lines of:

```
RssFeedDocument fd = ListName.Find(delegate(RssFeedDocument doc) { return doc.FeedID == someVariable; });
```